# How to extract SQL column and table information

Tags: c#, regex

I know this is very old and basic question but In my case this is bit different.

**Issue :** I have a string which contains data as below.

```
select * from table1; select col1,col2,col5 from table2; select col8 from table3;
```

I need to find a list of columns and the table name used from the above string.

I have tried it with `.lastIndexOf() and .SubString()` but it was not give exact output which I want.

**Desired Output:**

- Table name : "table2"    Columns Used : "col1, col2, col5"
- Table name : "table1"    Columns Used : "*"
- Table name : "table3"    Columns Used : "col8"

How should one go about extracting the above data?

Comment: This is not a basic question: the SQL grammar is complex, and parsing it is not easy.  Google for "sql parser" to find out more.  But I assume you only want to be able to parse a subset of the SQL grammar.  In which case you need to define what subset and dialects you want to support.  Just being able to parse a single example string isn't much use.

Comment: What @joe said, we can make it work for this one, however what about if you used a *CTE* and 1000 nested sql statements with joins and what not, i don't think anyone would want to be responsible for you maiming and injuring people with that code

Comment: Use `Split()` to separate it into separate statements, and then write the code to parse out the section between `SELECT` and `FROM` for each statement, use `Split` again on that section, and retrieve the list of column names. We're not going to write a SQL parser for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
    string storedProcContent = "select * from table1; select col1,col2,col5 from table2; select col8 from table3;";
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"select ([\w,\*]+?) from ([\w]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);
    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(storedProcContent);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}",
                       matches.Count, storedProcContent);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
        Console.WriteLine("Table name = {0}", groups[2].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Column Used = {0}", groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Output:

```
3 matches found in:
   select * from table1; select col1,col2,col5 from table2; select col8 from table3;
Table name = table1
Column Used = *
Table name = table2
Column Used = col1,col2,col5
Table name = table3
Column Used = col8
```